# How can I get the square root of a string

Tags: java, math

Good...
I need to get the square root of a string, I have not been able to get it, nor do I find a solution in other pages. Help.
I'm noob in this, please!

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class raiz {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a="9";
        Double result=Double.parseDouble(Math.sqrt(a));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "a string", do you mean a number represented as a string of numerals, taken as a decimal representation of a number? I don't know java, but I'd guess the answer involves converting a string to a number (e.g. "169"=>`169`).

Comment: `double result = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(a));`

Comment: Indeed. There is no such thing as "square root of a string".  You need a number.  as per the previous comment from Elliott Frisch.  -- the doc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Comment: @Beta 
Yes, I need that. I tried to convert it to decimal but it does not work , it gives me error or otherwise it gives me 0. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch the parseDouble and sqrt functions.  It needs to parse the number first, then compute the square root after it has been converted to a double.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class raiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "9";
        double result = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(a));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```